# Hit Enter on Button Give Diffrent Result

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, datagrid, onclick

I Have Function Export to Excel from datagridview, and i do test by try hit every button on my interface by press tab to locate the indicator to every button. but when on export button. it give me an error

```
DataGrid with id '' could not automatically generate any columns from the selected data source.
```

but when i click it with pointer/mouse , it works fine.

here's my export to excel code :

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        If CInquiry.SearchInquiry(txtAccount.Text, txtCustName.Text, txtAmount.Text, dropResponse.SelectedValue.ToString, txtInquiryDate.Text) Then
            dt = CInquiry.DT
        Else
            eMessage(CInquiry.eMsg)
        End If
        Dim DataGrd As New DataGrid()
        DataGrd.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        DataGrd.DataBind()

        Dim attachment As String
        attachment = "attachment; filename=Inquiry_Report" & Format(Now, "ddMMMyyyy") & ".xls"
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        DataGrd.RenderControl(htw)
        Response.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

the error is when datagrid try to bind the data, and the error is only raise when i do what i said above. whats wrong? is it onclick its mean click by pointer / mouse only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi actually i don't now the VB code but i can post c# code which may help you

```
 protected void lnkfiledownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string attachment = "attachment; filename=notification.xls";

        Response.ClearContent();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);

        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        // Create a form to contain the grid

        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();

        gvBranchNotification.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);

        frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";

        frm.Controls.Add(gvBranchNotification);

        frm.RenderControl(htw);



        Response.Write(sw.ToString());

        Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: it solve the error but it create a weird excel, which copy exactly like the page display